# How to run the selenium server in the background using robotframework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, selenium-grid

So the concept is like this -
I would like to run the selenium server .jar file on a remote windows machine.
Then connect to it via the default port (:4444), open browser and navigate to a URL of my choosing.
I have everything working except the part of running the selenium server through robot.

This keyword works as far as I can tell (until the open browser keyword) -

Start Selenium Server

```
&{client} =    Return Internal Host
Connect Environment Machine Windows    ${client}
start process    java    -jar    ${/}SeleniumServer${/}selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar    alias=seleniumserver
process should be running    seleniumserver
open browser    http://example.com/example.html  chrome    None    http://1.1.1.1:4444/wd/hub
```

BUT, when I try to connect to the selenium server I get the following error -
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

It seems like the process either does not run or runs for a short amount of time then closes.
What am I missing here?

If I manually start the server on the client, everything works. It opens the browser and does whatever I need. (manually running the java -jar selenium*.jar on the cmd)
But when I run this Start process keyword, that should keep the process running in the background, I get connection refused. Any Ideas?

Another piece of information that might be useful - The selenium server should throw an error if trying to run it twice on the same machine (because of the used port bind 4444).
When running the keyword shown above, while there is a selenium server up and running on the target machine, the test still passes for some reason. Not sure if it is even running the process as intended but the "process should be running" keyword seems to pass.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm willing to bet a firewall is blocking port 4444, or anti virus software is interfering.

Comment: In past I've done something similar and if I remember correctly selenium server need some time to be ready to accept connection. For test purpose add some sleep after you start the process. If It will help try to figure out if there is some sort of feedback that will help you to determine this moment (message in log, stdout).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the FW or Windows defender are not blocking anything because when I run the server locally, it opens the 4444 port and I am able to connect to it.
I will check it none the less.
Regarding the sleep time, good idea. Although it does go up pretty fast, maybe I need like a couple of seconds sleep before trying to connect.
Thanks for the suggestions! Will update on the outcome.

Comment: The sleep time didn't help. Any other ideas why the process won't run?
I suspect the path I give (I tried using a variable with the path in different syntaxes and also using the cwd= argument of start process, and using the "process should be running" providing the alias from the start process keyword.
example - 
start process java | -jar | ${path}/seleniumserver.jar | alias=seleniumserver
process should be running | seleniumserver

Comment: @sprunknwn Without additional logs and errors it's hard to tell. I've tried to run on my laptop similar setup and it works even without sleeps.

Comment: Hi JaPyR, Can you share what exactly you tried to run?

Comment: I tried multiple options yesterday, they all seem to pass but when I check the tasklist on the Windows machine, it does not show the java.exe running.
I tried start command, I tried execute command, I tried start and run process, I tried making a .bat file, I am using the "start /b command" to send it to the background. When I do it step by step manually, it works. When I run it through robot, I get no error but it doesn't run. What am I missing? If anyone has a working robot framework keyword to connect to a win machine and run the server in the bg, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @sprunknwn, not sure if comments section is best for such discussion, maybe try robotframework forum, but why are you using 1.1.1.1 in your example? If you are starting server at the same machine where robot is run it should be localhost.
When it comes to my example I start server in suite setup `Start Process    java    -jar    selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar    shell=${True}` and than just use in `Open Browser` keyword `remote_url=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`

Comment: @JaPyR - I need to connect to a remote windows client and run the open browser test there. This is why I need the Selenium server to run there so I can connect to it and run my test.
Reason being is that the windows 10 client is behind a gateway I am testing enforcement on. Where the actual robot script runs and starts from, you can call it, a robot server. It connects to all necessary parts of the test, runs what is needed and then exits and provides a log of the test.